# Sending time ordered events into Kafka

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, azure-databricks

I am using Autoloader (from Databricks) to ingest some parquet files and send them later to a Kafka topic.

I am able to read the files and write them without any problem but I have doubts about the order.

These files contain a `timestamp` field inside the payload which indicates the modification date of the file.

Is it possible to write each of the events that I receive with the autoloader in the Kafka sink ordered by that date?

I would like to be able to write in Kafka from the oldest to the newest events based on this `timestamp`.

I have considered to define a function that is going to be invoked the `foreachBatch` in which it makes a simple `orderBy` for each batch.
Something like this:

```scala
def orderByFunc ( batchDF:DataFrame, batchID:Long ) : Unit = {

  val rodered_df=batchDF.orderBy($"some_field".desc) // order by the timestamp field
  rodered_df.write.format("kafka").option(...) // write into Kafka
 
}

streamingInputDF
                .writeStream
                .queryName(job_name)
                .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
                .foreachBatch(orderByFunc _)
                .start()
```

Is there a less cumbersome way? am I missing something?

Thank you very much to all

Comment: Note: While this may work for Spark, it will order _per Spark partition_, not necessarily guarantee that Kafka actually receives and stores any of its partition in absolute ordering. Especially if there are multiple producers at once. For that, you need to ensure there is only one Spark executor, which kinda defeats the purpose of using Spark

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply @OneCricketeer . At the moment I am working with a single partition as it is a test and the dataset is small. But effectively this breaks with the essential operation of Spark, the parallelism. I have tried to find posts on the internet that talk about event ordering using Spark as a producer and have not been able to find out anything of value. Thanks again :)

Comment: if the files are stored in DBFS or S3, or whereever, you should send just the URI to the file through as an event, then let Kafka consumers download the files and process them (which could be local Spark tasks). That way the consumption and processing can then be distributed